# Select item from drop down menu and insert in body of new message to edit

Tags: android, xml, drop-down-menu, smsmanager

I want to insert my drop down menu selected item in the edit text of body of new message so that i can edit the text and made necessary updates if required. My xml code for edit text is:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editSMS"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="132dp"
android:gravity="top"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:lines="9" />
```

code to select item from drop down menu

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
```

and code for new message

```
editSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSMS);
public void onClick(View v) {
             String phoneNo = editPhoneNum.getText().toString();
             String sms = label +    editSMS.getText().toString();
             try {
                     SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                     smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


             } catch (Exception e) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
```

Code to load spinner data

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
        // database handler
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
            // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> lables = db.getAllNames();
            // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: when i select item from drop down menu it nedd be automatically shown in edittext box

Comment: editSms.setText(lable);

Comment: its showing error "Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type void"

Comment: what is your parent?? adapter view?? you must be having some arraylist or vector where you are storing the string which are to be shown before selecting the item     

are you getting the toast correctly??

Answer (score 0):

Add do your drop down item selected listener. Cast parent to appropriate view class first, and then get selected item

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    label = ((Spinner) parent).getSelectedItem().toString();
        // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    EditText etSMS= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSMS);
    etSMS.setText(label);

    }
```

Comment: How do you know that he is using a spinner??

Comment: I said "Cast parent to appropriate view class first", to Spinner or whatever is appropriate is for him/her